# Attach ruby-debug-ide to existing Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, ruby-debug-ide

#### Background

I have `ruby-debug-ide` all setup to remote debug (I'm using Docker) in Visual Studio Code. I am using this command in my `docker-compose.yml` to start `ruby-debug-ide` and my rails server:

```
rm -f /api/tmp/pids/server.pid && rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 -- bin/rails server --port=3000 --binding=0.0.0.0
```

and then in vscode I have this launch.json script:

```
{
  "name": "Listen for rdebug-ide",
  "type": "Ruby",
  "request": "attach",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "remoteHost": "127.0.0.1",
  "remotePort": "1234",
  "remoteWorkspaceRoot": "/app",
  "showDebuggerOutput": true
}
```

and when I go to vscode and start that launch.json script, my rails server starts up as well as the debugger. But when I stop/detach the launch.json script, the rails server dies.

#### My Question

Is there a way to start my Rails server and `ruby-debug-ide` independently? I want to be able to access my Rails application when I am **not** debugging. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
# start my rails server
rm -f /api/tmp/pids/server.pid && bin/rails server --port=3000 --binding=0.0.0.0

# also start rdebug-ide and wait for something (vscode) to attach to it later on
rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 -- <attach_to_my_rails_server>
```

Comment: Apparently it is a feature requested -> https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/issues/125 but not yet implemented

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this: 
`rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 -- bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Yes, that was my first attempt. `rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 -- bin/rails server --port=3000 --binding=0.0.0.0` and then my rails app wouldn't start until i attached the debugger.